Почему не работает цикл? js
Скажите пожалуйста почему у меня не работает цикл и как это исправить?
Сначала я не мог понять почему мне в консоль выходило 1, хотя должно другое число, после чего посмотрел в DevTools и по брэкпоинтам понял, что цикл не работает и сразу перескакивает дальше.


function amountOfPages(summary) {
  let num = 0;
  let lengthOfI = 1;

  function calculationlength(t) {
    let g = t.toString()
    return g.length;
  }
  for (let i = summary; i < 0; i = i - lengthOfI) {
    num = num + 1;
    lengthOfI = calculationlength(num);
  }
  if (num == 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return num;
  }
}

console.log(amountOfPages(25));




Ну если summary больше 0, то с чего бы ему работать? У вас условие i < 0 не выполняется.

Нужно знак поменять
(let i = summary; i > 0; i = i - lengthOfI)


У вас обратный цикл, а это условие не правильное
for (let i = summary; i < 0; i = i - lengthOfI)

Замените на это
for (let i = summary; i > 0; i -= lengthOfI)



function amountOfPages(summary) {
  let num = 0;
  let lengthOfI = 1;

  function calculationlength(t) {
    return t.toString().length;
  }

  for (let i = summary; i > 0; i -= lengthOfI) {
    num += 1;
    lengthOfI = calculationlength(num);
  }

  return num > 0 ? num : 1;
}

console.log(amountOfPages(25));



